# Best redundant approach for server / client communications in C#

Tags: c#, rest, websocket, servicestack, tcpclient

I have a product that is fielded and works at a basic level.  It uses self-hosted ServiceStack  and Redis for the database on the server.  For the client, is also uses ServiceStack to receive data periodically.  The clients connect to the server for data about once per hour, but the connection and transfer needs to be within seconds (not normally a problem).  The data is only about 100 json characters.

I have found problems on the client machine.  Because the client lives at a brokerage, at the market open when I need my small amount of data to be received by the client, I can get shut out by the thousands of other systems trying to get market data at the open.  So I now have the broker restarting my system after the open, because it doesn't recover well.

The question I have is, what is the best way to make a robust system in this type of bad network environment?

Some ideas I've had are to add a websocket connection, so that I'm not establishing a new connection for every poll interval (with the REST API).  For example, I already found that DNS was a problem during these market surges, so I plan to do a lookup once and then just hold the IP address internally for all later connections.

So I'm thinking of seeing whatever comes in, either the REST data or the websocket data, and just go with whatever data set is available.  I wanted to check and see if others had seen this kind of case and any architectural thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Websockets (SignalR)](http://www.asp.net/signalr) is a great option for your specific implementation. However you should keep in mind, since you indicated concerns around the reliability of your connection, in websockets, the client initiates the connection, if your connection fails, the server will detect this but since your browser will not, it will not be getting any updates. [Read here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) to see how you can possibly increase the reliability of your connections.

Comment: I tagged this as the answer because it includes some really good links for background.  But in actuality my client is not a browser, but another C# program.  I plan to use Alchemy for the websockets.

Comment: You can use SignalR for c# clients too: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client